# Java: preorderEnumeration in TreeModel, how to get depthindex and sibling index?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

```
    for (Enumeration e = root.preorderEnumeration(); e.hasMoreElements() && theNode == null;) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();

    }
```

For that example above, how can you find out how deep you are in the tree branch? If you are iterating over siblings, how do you get it's index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the depth by counting the number of parents iterating on `getParent()` from `node` until result is `null`.

You can get `node`'s index thanks to `node.getIndex(node.getParent())`.

If you need both information for each node you traverse, I recommend you for efficiency to write your own traversor code, either inspired from `DefaultMutableTreeNode.getNextNode()` or `DefaultMutableTreeNode.PreorderEnumeration` inner class. In that later case, the generated stack should contain a structure `{ node, treeDepth, siblingIndex }`

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel, there's api for getting the node's distance from the root: node.getLevel() Wasn't aware of it until recently, skimming the api doc works wonders :-)

Comment: I agree. getLevel() does exactly the count I describe but it is not efficient if you need that information for each node.